# effect of loading files from mysql database on site performance

Tags: mysql, performance, effect

I've a website that all of it's images are loading from MySQL database.
Sometimes when many clients connect to the site, it slows down & I'm doing some optimizations on my server & codes to increase total performance.
As a candidate of change, I want to know that moving files out of the database & loading from static files instead of dynamically generated contents, can cause any significant improvement on my performance?
If yes, is there any benchmark available about it?

Comment: Voting to close the question as OP has indicated in comments that he seeks to understand how this impacts the performance in his environment. This gets to a broader issue of how to run performance tests on an application/environment and determine performance bottlenecks.  This can;t hope to be covered in a simple SO question.

Comment: Request for a benchmark is also off topic.

Answer (score 2):

Storing images in a database is generally a bad idea, yet you see lots of people doing it without any good reason.

In 99% of cases I would recommend only storing file path references to the images in the database and have the images stored statically.

Here are some reasons why:

- You don't tie up both the application server and the databases server transmitting images to the browser, you can offload this to web server itself which is more optimized for this.
- If you have a sizeable site, you would eventually want to move static images onto a CDN anyway. You can't do this with files in database
- You application will be slower when trying to insert images into the database, as you basically have to upload file to application server, then turn around and write into the DB as opposed to simply writing the path reference.
- You DB itself could grow in size at a significant rate with enough images. You don't want to tie up your DB file system with a bunch of files that can be stored at low cost in other ways (like distributed file storage services like Amazon S3)

Comment: This is NOT my answer too (like the previous post!), I just want to know that is there any evidence that loading files from database decrease overall performance or not?

Comment: @EhsanKhodarahmi You would have to test that in your specific application to determine the impact that this approach has and whether it is even one of the largest performance problems that you want to focus on correcting.  We don't know you application or its environment, so we can't be of much help there.

Comment: @EhsanKhodarahmi You didn't ask for evidence: you asked whether it was true. Mike has given you four plausible reasons why it is true.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation to yours. The solution is simple: cache the content.

When you run the first time the query to get an image, ie:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = 1
```

Then simply cache the result to a file:

```
file_put_contents("image1.png",$row['data']);
```

Next time simply check whenever there is the file, this will avoid to query the database

Comment: This is not the answer of my question because I'm not sure caching can improve the performance!

Comment: Caching of course can improve the performance, especially when it avoids you to run a query to your database. Because storing/querying images in the database is expensive

Comment: @EhsanKhodarahmi You being unsure isn't a reason why this isn't an answer. Caching almost always improves performance. This is not controversial.

Comment: @EJP I'm seeking for a reasonable & exact answer, because I can't make a big change in my code to test whether it makes a meaningful effect or not! & of course "expensive" is not a precise answer in my opinion!